# when trying to save listbox items to text file i get error

Tags: vb.net

so i am tring to make all of listbox1 items to a text file and i keep getting the error "'item' is not a member of 'String()'"

where i get the error: `w.WriteLine(ListBox1.items.Item(i))`

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\ProxyGrabber")
        Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\ProxyGrabbe\test.txt")
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.items.Count - 1
            w.WriteLine(ListBox1.items.Item(i))
        Next
        w.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: That line, though redundant redundant. wont cause that error.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and get back to us when you find the real problem line. umat

Comment: You do realize that your directory ProxyGrabber does not match ProxyGrabbe , Yes?

Comment: yes i also tried  w.WriteLine(x.ToString) but i only get an empty text file

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox1.items.Item(i)
```

returns an object type. If the listbox items are simply strings, all you need to do is change

```
w.WriteLine(ListBox1.items.Item(i))
```

to

```
w.WriteLine(CType(ListBox1.Items.Item(i), String))
```